# How do i get the node-names from xml_parser()

Tags: php, xml, parsing, slice

I try to pre-sort and slice a big XML file for later processing via xml_parser

```
    function CreateXMLParser($CHARSET, $bareXML = false) {
      $CURRXML = xml_parser_create($CHARSET);
      xml_parser_set_option( $CURRXML, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, false);
      xml_parser_set_option( $CURRXML, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, $CHARSET);
      xml_set_element_handler($CURRXML, 'startElement', 'endElement');
      xml_set_character_data_handler($CURRXML, 'dataHandler');
      xml_set_default_handler($CURRXML, 'defaultHandler');
      if ($bareXML) {
         xml_parse($CURRXML, '<?xml version="1.0"?>', 0);
        }               
      return $CURRXML;
      }

    function ChunkXMLBigFile($file, $tag = 'item', $howmany = 1000) {
         global $CHUNKON, $CHUNKS, $ITEMLIMIT;  

         $CHUNKON   = $tag;
         $ITEMLIMIT = $howmany; 
         $xml = CreateXMLParser('UTF-8', false);

         $fp = fopen($file, "r");
         $CHUNKS  = 0;
         while(!feof($fp)) {
              $chunk = fgets($fp, 10240);                     
              xml_parse($xml, $chunk, feof($fp));
         }
         xml_parser_free($xml);              
         processChunk();
    }
function processChunk() {
    global $CHUNKS, $PAYLOAD, $ITEMCOUNT;
    if ('' == $PAYLOAD) {
        return;
        }

    $xp = fopen($file = "xmlTemp/slices/slice_".$CHUNKS.".xml", "w");
    fwrite($xp, '<?xml version="1.0" ?>'."\n");
    fwrite($xp, "<producten>");
    fwrite($xp, $PAYLOAD);
    fwrite($xp, "</producten>");
    fclose($xp);
    print "Written ".$file."<br>";
    $CHUNKS++;
    $PAYLOAD    = '';
    $ITEMCOUNT  = 0;
    }



 function startElement($xml, $tag, $attrs = array())  {
    global $PAYLOAD, $CHUNKS, $ITEMCOUNT, $CHUNKON;

    if (!($CHUNKS||$ITEMCOUNT)) {
        if ($CHUNKON == strtolower($tag)) {
            $PAYLOAD = '';
            }                
        } else {
        $PAYLOAD .= "<".$tag;
        } 
    foreach($attrs as $k => $v) {
        $PAYLOAD .= " $k=".'"'.addslashes($v).'"';
        }            
    $PAYLOAD .= '>';
    }


 function endElement($xml, $tag) {
    global $CHUNKON, $ITEMCOUNT, $ITEMLIMIT;

    dataHandler(null, "<$tag>");
    if ($CHUNKON == strtolower($tag)) {
        if (++$ITEMCOUNT >= $ITEMLIMIT) {
            processChunk();
            }                
        }             
    }

 function dataHandler($xml, $data) {
    global $PAYLOAD;
    $PAYLOAD .= $data;
    }
```

but how can I access the node-name??

.. I have to sort some items (with *n* nodes) out, before the slice-file is saved. the the XML is parsed line after line, right? so I have to save the nodes from a whole item temporarely and decide if the item is gonna be written to the file.. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is effectively reading the entire source file every time you call the `ChunkXMLBigFile` function.

After your `while` loop you have all the elements, which you can then manipulate any way you like.

See the following questions about how to approach this:

- [How to sort a xml file using DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528287/how-to-sort-a-xml-file-using-dom)
- [Sort XML nodes with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788404/sort-xml-nodes-with-php)

If you parse the chunks after that in batches of `$howmany` you are where you want to be.

---

Tip: there are many examples online where this functionality is presented in an Object Orient Programming (OOP) approach where all the functions are inside a class. This would also eliminate the need of `global` variables which can cause some (read: a lot) of frustrations and confusion.